# Strange behavior with String.to_integer/1

Tags: elixir

I have something strange in Elixir with `String.to_integer`. Nothing major, but I would like to know if there's a way to chain all my functions with the pipe operator.

Here is the problem. This line of code (you can try in "iex"):

```
[5, 6, 7, 3] 
|> Enum.reverse 
|> Enum.map_join "", &(Integer.to_string(&1))
```

returns the string `"3765"`

What I want is an integer. So I just have to add this little piece of code `|> String.to_integer` at the end the previous statement and I should have a integer. Let's try. This piece of code:

```
[5, 6, 7, 3] 
|> Enum.reverse 
|> Enum.map_join "", &(Integer.to_string(&1)) 
|> String.to_integer
```

gives me this: `"3765"`. Not an integer, a string!

If I do that though:

```
a = [5, 6, 7, 3] 
|> Enum.reverse 
|> Enum.map_join "", &(Integer.to_string(&1)) 
String.to_integer(a)
```

It returns me an integer: `3765`.

It's what I'm doing right now but it makes me mad because I would love to chain all these function the good way with the amazing pipe operator.

Thanks for the help or the lights. Elixir is very fun!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add parentheses around the arguments to `map_join`. Currently, your code is interpreted as

```
[5, 6, 7, 3] 
|> Enum.reverse 
|> Enum.map_join("", &(Integer.to_string(&1) |> String.to_integer))
```

what you want is though

```
[5, 6, 7, 3] 
|> Enum.reverse 
|> Enum.map_join("", &(Integer.to_string(&1)))
|> String.to_integer
```

Generally, you always need to use parentheses when you are using captures inside a pipeline to avoid ambiguities. The capture can also be simplified to `&Integer.to_string/1`:

```
[5, 6, 7, 3] 
|> Enum.reverse 
|> Enum.map_join("", &Integer.to_string/1)
|> String.to_integer
```

But a plain `Enum.join` will do the same thing. If you look at [the implementation](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/84262257ef183513fa45a780dadf6564931cc399/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L938-L943), it will convert the integers to strings anyway, using [the `String.Chars` protocol](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/84262257ef183513fa45a780dadf6564931cc399/lib/elixir/lib/string/chars.ex#L47-L51).

```
[5, 6, 7, 3] 
|> Enum.reverse 
|> Enum.join
|> String.to_integer
```

By the way, you can achieve the same thing without using strings at all:

```
[5, 6, 7, 3] 
|> Enum.reverse 
|> Enum.reduce(0, &(&2 * 10 + &1))
```

Oh, and then there's [`Integer.digits`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/Integer.html#digits/2) and [`Integer.undigits`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/Integer.html#undigits/2), which can be used to convert an Integer to and from a list of digits. It's not present in the current release, though it is in the `1.1.0-dev` branch so I suspect it will come in `1.1.0`. You can watch the progress [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/milestones).

```
[5, 6, 7, 3] 
|> Enum.reverse 
|> Integer.undigits
```

Comment: This is why I am generally against optional parens. In a few cases it is nice to have, but I think it is generally better to create a habit of always putting parens where needed.

Comment: @Patrick Oh man, it's so helpful. Thanks for the explanation about the parenthesis and for the better and nicer alternative solution. I'm stilling it if you don't mind :-)